# makefile error - Unity testing framework - Keil uvision 5 - STM32CubeMx

Tags: c, unit-testing, makefile, keil, unity-test-framework

I have been trying to integrate  **Unity Testing Framework**  into Keil version 5, naturally I faced a lot of issues and errors and was able to solve a lot of them, now I am facing an error that I would like to get your support with.

**A brief summary:**

This is my thesis project, which is Embedded software testing and the implementation teams are using Keil uvision 5 with code skeleton and configuration generated using STM32CubeMx for the development of a self-driving car project at my university.

**The enviroment**

```
OS: Windows 10
IDE-Version:
µVision V5.24.2.0
Tool Version Numbers:
Toolchain:        MDK-ARM Professional  Version: 5.24.1
Toolchain Path:    C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin
C Compiler:         Armcc.exe        V5.06 update 5 (build 528)
Assembler:          Armasm.exe        V5.06 update 5 (build 528)
Linker/Locator:     ArmLink.exe        V5.06 update 5 (build 528)
Library Manager:    ArmAr.exe        V5.06 update 5 (build 528)
Hex Converter:      FromElf.exe        V5.06 update 5 (build 528)
CPU DLL:               SARMCM3.DLL          V5.24.1
Dialog DLL:         DCM.DLL              V1.16.0.0
Target DLL:             STLink\ST-LINKIII-KEIL_SWO.dll      V3.0.1.0
Dialog DLL:         TCM.DLL              V1.32.0.0
Practice board: STM32F446ZETx
```

**The approach**

I plan to integrate Unity FW by using a makefile to compile and run the tests in the pre-build option available withing Keil. for now I am trying to make the makefile work using commandline outside Keil, once it works, I believe it will easy to just run it with a make command from Keil pre-build option. I followed this tutorial to create the makefile http://www.throwtheswitch.org/build/make

I edited the makefile by adding the appropriate armcc and armlinker with the commandline options that were present in the keil configuration of the project and the arm compiler alternatives for what the tutorial was adding to their gcc as you will see in the makefile below

**The structure**

The following is sample structure of a Blinky project using TIM10 timer created using STM32CubeMx and Unity FW is added manually to the folder

```
--root
----Drivers
--------CMSIS --> "Drivers related files"
--------STM32F4xx_HAL-Driver --> "Drivers related files"
----Inc
---------gpio.h
---------main.h
---------stm32f4xx_hal_config.h
---------stm32f4xx_it.h
---------tim.h
----MDK-ARM
---------"Other STM32 related folders and files"
----Src
---------gpio.c
---------main.c
---------stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c
---------stm32f4xx_hal_config.c
---------stm32f4xx_it.c
---------tim.c
----Unity
---------build
-------------depends --> "autogenerated by makefile"
-------------objs --> "autogenerated by makefile"
-------------results --> "autogenerated by makefile"
-------------testing --> "autogenerated by makefile"
-------------TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.map
---------src
-------------stm32f4xx_hal.h
-------------unity_internals.h
-------------unity.c
-------------unity.h
---------test
-------------Testgpio.c
--.mxproject
--makefile
--mx.scratch
--TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.ioc
```

**The makefile**

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  ifeq ($(shell uname -s),) # not in a bash-like shell
    CLEANUP = del /F /Q
    MKDIR = mkdir
  else # in a bash-like shell, like msys
    CLEANUP = rm -f
    MKDIR = mkdir -p
  endif
    TARGET_EXTENSION=exe
else
    CLEANUP = rm -f
    MKDIR = mkdir -p
    TARGET_EXTENSION=out
endif

.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: test

PATHU = Unity/src/
PATHS = Src/
PATHI = Unity/src/
PATHI2 = Inc
PATHI3 = Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
PATHI4 = Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
PATHI5 = Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
PATHI6 = Drivers/CMSIS/Include
PATHT = Unity/test/
PATHB = Unity/build/testing/
PATHD = Unity/build/depends/
PATHO = Unity/build/objs/
PATHR = Unity/build/results/

BUILD_PATHS = $(PATHB) $(PATHD) $(PATHO) $(PATHR)

SRCT = $(wildcard $(PATHT)*.c)

COMPILE=armcc -c --cpu Cortex-M4.fp -D__MICROLIB -g -O3 --apcs=interwork --split_sections
LINK=armlink --library_type=microlib --libpath="C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\lib" --strict --scatter "MDK-ARM\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.sct" --diag_suppress=L6329 --summary_stderr --info summarysizes --map --xref --callgraph --symbols --info sizes --info totals --info unused --info veneers --list "TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.map" -o "MDK-ARM\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.axf"
DEPEND=armcc --no_depend_system_headers --depend_dir=$(PATHD)
CFLAGS=-I. -I$(PATHU) -I$(PATHS) -I$(PATHI) -I$(PATHI2) -I$(PATHI3) -I$(PATHI4) -I$(PATHI5) -I$(PATHI6)

RESULTS = $(patsubst $(PATHT)Test%.c,$(PATHR)Test%.txt,$(SRCT) )

PASSED = `grep -s PASS $(PATHR)*.txt`
FAIL = `grep -s FAIL $(PATHR)*.txt`
IGNORE = `grep -s IGNORE $(PATHR)*.txt`

test: $(BUILD_PATHS) $(RESULTS)
    @echo "-----------------------\nIGNORES:\n-----------------------"
    @echo "$(IGNORE)"
    @echo "-----------------------\nFAILURES:\n-----------------------"
    @echo "$(FAIL)"
    @echo "-----------------------\nPASSED:\n-----------------------"
    @echo "$(PASSED)"
    @echo "\nDONE"

$(PATHR)%.txt: $(PATHB)%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION)
    -./$< > $@ 2>&1

$(PATHB)Test%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION): $(PATHO)Test%.o $(PATHO)%.o $(PATHU)unity.o $(PATHD)Test%.d
    $(LINK) $@ $^

$(PATHO)%.o:: $(PATHT)%.c
    $(COMPILE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(PATHO)%.o:: $(PATHS)%.c
    $(COMPILE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(PATHO)%.o:: $(PATHU)%.c $(PATHU)%.h
    $(COMPILE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(PATHD)%.d:: $(PATHT)%.c
    $(DEPEND) $@ $<

$(PATHB):
    $(MKDIR) $(PATHB)

$(PATHD):
    $(MKDIR) $(PATHD)

$(PATHO):
    $(MKDIR) $(PATHO)

$(PATHR):
    $(MKDIR) $(PATHR)

clean:
    $(CLEANUP) $(PATHO)*.o
    $(CLEANUP) $(PATHB)*.$(TARGET_EXTENSION)
    $(CLEANUP) $(PATHR)*.txt

.PRECIOUS: $(PATHB)Test%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION)
.PRECIOUS: $(PATHD)%.d
.PRECIOUS: $(PATHO)%.o
.PRECIOUS: $(PATHR)%.txt
```

**The current output and error**

```
$ makecc -I. -IUnity/src/ -ISrc/ -IUnity/src/ -IInc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include   -c -o Unity/src/unity.o Unity/src/unity.c
armcc --no_depend_system_headers --depend_dir=Unity/build/depends/ Unity/build/depends/Testgpio.d Unity/test/Testgpio.c
Error: C4065E: type of input file 'Unity/build/depends/Testgpio.d' unknown

make: *** [makefile:74: Unity/build/depends/Testgpio.d] Error 1
rm Unity/src/unity.o
```

**UPDATE -- simple makefile to test dependency error**

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
TAR = $(SRC:.c=.d)
DEPEND=armcc --no_depend_system_headers

all: $(TAR)

%.d: %.c
    $(DEPEND) $@ $<
```

Unfortunately it returned `armcc --no_depend_system_headers test.d test.c
Error: C4065E: type of input file 'test.d' unknow`

but when changed the compiler and flags into

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
TAR = $(SRC:.c=.d)
DEPEND=gcc -MM -MG -MF

all: $(TAR)

%.d: %.c
    $(DEPEND) $@ $<
```

it worked and test.d is created from test.c -- all files are in the same folder

**Update**

I have managed to get the armcc to work, after checking the docs I updated my makefile as follows:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
TAR = $(SRC:.c=.d)
DEPEND=armcc --no_depend_system_headers --ignore_missing_headers --md --depend

all: $(TAR)

%.d: %.c
    $(DEPEND) $@ $<
```

with makefile and the source file in the same folder it works fine.

Now, when returned to the main makefile and updated the DEPEND flags to the following

`armcc --no_depend_system_headers --ignore_missing_headers --md --depend`

It returned a different error, that has to do with armlink, I do not know how the process goes, what is fired first and which depends on the other, but the fact remains when I run make now it gives the following error:

```
$ make
cc -I. -IUnity/src/ -ISrc/ -IUnity/src/ -IInc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include   -c -o Unity/src/unity.o Unity/src/unity.c
armlink --library_type=microlib --libpath="C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\lib" --strict --scatter "MDK-ARM\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.sct" --diag_suppress=L6329 --summary_stderr --info summarysizes --map --xref --callgraph --symbols --info sizes --info totals --info unused --info veneers --list "TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.map" -o "MDK-ARM\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1\TIM10_LED_1_Ceedling_try1.axf" Unity/build/testing/Testgpio.exe Unity/build/objs/Testgpio.o Unity/build/objs/gpio.o Unity/src/unity.o
Fatal error: L6002U: Could not open file Unity/build/testing/Testgpio.exe: No such file or directory
Finished: 0 information, 0 warning, 0 error and 1 fatal error messages.
make: *** [makefile:62: Unity/build/testing/Testgpio.exe] Error 1
rm Unity/src/unity.o
```

I will continue working on it, but if someone can help please do

**great Update!**

The previous error is gone and I am starting to see actual progress !
I commented out $(PATHD)Test%.d in the LINK step as it was commented out in the orignal file I got, when I included it, the error is gone and I am now facing syntax errors and warning from actual files :) please check below and advise

```
$ make
armcc --no_depend_system_headers --ignore_missing_headers --depend Unity/build/depends/Testgpio.d Unity/test/Testgpio.c
"Unity/test/Testgpio.c", line 13: Warning:  #223-D: function "TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL" declared implicitly
      TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(2, AddFunction_ReturnCorrect(1, 1));
      ^
"Unity/test/Testgpio.c", line 13: Warning:  #223-D: function "AddFunction_ReturnCorrect" declared implicitly
      TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(2, AddFunction_ReturnCorrect(1, 1));
                           ^
"Unity/test/Testgpio.c", line 19: Warning:  #223-D: function "UnityBegin" declared implicitly
        UnityBegin("test/Testgpio.c");
        ^
"Unity/test/Testgpio.c", line 20: Warning:  #223-D: function "RUN_TEST" declared implicitly
        RUN_TEST(test_AddFunction_ReturnCorrect_ShouldReturnCorrectSum);
        ^
"Unity/test/Testgpio.c", line 22: Warning:  #223-D: function "UnityEnd" declared implicitly
        return (UnityEnd());
                ^
Unity/test/Testgpio.c: 5 warnings, 0 errors
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol AddFunction_ReturnCorrect (referred from Testgpio.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol RUN_TEST (referred from Testgpio.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL (referred from Testgpio.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol UnityBegin (referred from Testgpio.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol UnityEnd (referred from Testgpio.o).
Finished: 0 information, 0 warning and 5 error messages.
make: *** [makefile:74: Unity/build/depends/Testgpio.d] Error 1
```

**Update**

I am not what is happening here, after 3 4 makes the previous error returned

**Update**

OK so If I delete the build folder and run make, it gives the L6218E errors, if I run make again it gives the L6002U error. Also someone can explain why at the end of each make it runs `rm Unity/src/unity.o` ?

Comment: What happens if you add a rule `%.d: %.c \n\t $(DEPEND) $@ @<`?

Comment: thanks for the reply, no change added the rule after the original depend rule but same error occured

Comment: In your tree `testgpio`, but in your rules it's called `Testgpio` (or actually `Test%d`. Please check the `t` vs `T`.

Comment: If that ^^^ is not it I'd make a tiny `Makefile` from scratch that should just generates the `.d` file. Just to focus on that issue and get it right.

Comment: its a typo in the structure I made, it is Testgpio.c in reallity, when you say make a tiny makefile from scratch, which parts should I include ? I am have very small experience with makefiles

Comment: Just one rule to generate a `.d` from a `.c` (see above, make sure the command, second line, starts with a TAB), run it in a directory that has one `.c` and see if the `.d` is generated. Could use the `make` `-n` (dryrun just printing commands) and/or `-d` (print debug info) options. Your makefile is not complicated and it must be something simple/small we're overlooking.

Comment: good call! it seems there is something wrong with the .d extention - I made a simple makefile and i got the same error
Note: I tried with `gcc -MM -MG -MF` and it worked 
you think there is some conflicting or missing flag with armcc ?
I will update the answer with the simple file I made

Comment: Are you sure that Keil will produce dependencies with the `DEPEND=armcc --no_depend_system_headers` command line? To me it seems there is something like the gcc `-M` switches missing.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes, I managed to find the equivalent of 2 of the 3 flags of gcc in the docs of ARM [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/CIHJGCEJ.html) but I could not find the 3rd which is -MG, if you know please tell me maybe thats what missing, although I doubt it